# why does mailx ignore header fields?

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, mailx, cl

I want to send an HTML email.
have a plain text file that looks like this:

```
From: "name" <name@email.com>
To: name@email.com
Subject: First Email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline

<strong>Hello, World!</strong>
```

I run `mailx` like this,

```
mailx -t -S smtp=server.com name@email.com  < file
```

It sends a plain-text email instead and prints:

```
Ignoring header field "MIME-Version: 1.0"
Ignoring header field "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii"
Ignoring header field "Content-Disposition: inline"
```

**Why?

How do I send an html email?**

Other sources say to use the `-a` flag and specify the content-type,
but `-a` on my version of `mailx` is attachment; so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When using option `-t`, *mailx* filters out header fields and only keeps the following ones:

- `to:`
- `cc:`
- `bcc:`
- `from:`
- `reply-to:`
- `sender:`
- `organization:`

Any other header produces the ["Ignoring header field"](https://github.com/scallywag/mailx/blob/master/head.c#L338) warning message and is discarded.

This is effectively cryptic in the manual.